# copy part of a redirected URL as text

Tags: python

OK, here's basically what I am trying to do:

Let's say I have an URL as input, and that URL redirects to another one.
Well, I need to write down a part of the second URL

Example:

`www.whatever.com/search/dunno` redirects to `www.whatever.com/database/important_part`

What I need is to write "important_part" in a file.

Maybe it's a stupid thing, but I'm very new to this stuff, sorry.

EDIT - Better example:

The URL [http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=animelist&adb.search="Cowboy Bebop"&do.search=search](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=animelist&adb.search=%22Cowboy%20Bebop%22&do.search=search) redirects to http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=23

Let's say I want to write down the ID (23, in that example).

Comment: Do you simply need the last part of the url after the forward slash or do you want the different part of the two urls eg. database/important_part

Comment: edited - it should be clearer now

Answer (score 1):

You want the [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) module:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
parsed_url = urlparse("www.whatever.com/database/important_part")
log_file.write("Redirected to: {p}\n".format(p=parsed_url.path.split('/')[-1]))
```

Comment: Howcome you need urlparse for this? It seems like parsed_url.path is the same as `"www.whatever.com/database/important_part"`

Comment: Well, it should use www.whatever.com/search/dunno as input.

Comment: urlparse handles everything about the URL, so it's not thrown off by form parameters (`...?name=value&name=value...`) and fragments (`...#frag_id`). If you can guarantee that the URL has had these things stripped off, you can just use the last line, replacing `parsed_url.path` with your string variable.